# Verb adjective pattern

Tags: verbs, adjectives

> She stood tall and started to talk normal.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?  If so, what to make of the apparently wrong verb+adjective pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The verb needs an adverb "normally".

[This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talk%20normally%20%2C%20talk%20normal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalk%20normally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalk%20normal%3B%2Cc0) shows the preference of the phrase "to talk normally".

Comment: Thanks.  Still curious why there is "talk normal" in the first place.  Also, is "stood tall" a phrase? Or because "stood" could be seen as a linking verb?

Comment: Yes, some action verbs develop meanings of linking  verbs: to go wrong, to come true, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's open to interpretation, in *talk normal*, I would consider *normal* to be the noun form of the word.

For example: *talk English,* *talk French*, *talk a strange tongue*, *talk normal*. It's not describing *how* someone speaks, but *what* they speak.

You could also look at it as an elided form of a more complete phrase. For example:

> ✘ Talk normally English.
>   ✔ Talk normal English.

In this comparison, it only makes sense to use *normal*, not *normally*. And, in the case of simply *talk normal*, *English* can be thought of as dropped. Although it's a bit unusual, it's not wrong.

If the sentence actually *is* meant to describe the manner of her speech, then, yes, I would say that the adverb (*normally*) would be more common. But note that we have road signs that say *drive slow* rather than *drive slowly*, and nobody misunderstands the adverbial use of *slow*. Using a word that doesn't end with *-ly* as an adverb may not be as common, but it's still quite acceptable.

---

In *stood tall*, although *tall* itself is an adjective, it is being used here *as* an adverb. It describes *how* she stood. Adverbs normally take an *-ly* form, but there are also flat adverbs, as well as words and phrases that can be used as adverbs in some constructions. It's the latter that's happening here.

As an example:

> She is **faster** than him.

Here, *faster* is an adjective. It describes a quality that she possesses.

> She ran **faster** than him.

Here, *faster* (while actually an adjective), is being used as an adverb within the syntax of the sentence. It describes how she ran. There is no such adverb as *fasterly* that could be used instead—nor do we need to invent one simply to have a word that ends in *-ly*.

---

Interestingly, [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tall) has this entry:

> **Phrases**
>
> **walk (or stand) tall**
>   Be proud and confident.

Checking back with [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand%20tall), it also has something similar for the phrase:

> : to exhibit courage, strength, or calm especially in the face of adversity

This is a figurative sense, however, and it means something different from the literal physical sense of walking or standing tall that I'd been describing up until now.

Comment: Great explanation! So the "adjectives" turn out to be either a noun or a flat adverb.  Interestingly though, there is no mention of "tall" as an adverb in the Oxford/Cambridge dictionaries when I checked, but it is in the Merriam-Webster dictionary. Just wondering if the British would rather treat "stand/walk tall" as a set pharse?

Comment: @tiaotiao It turns out that Oxford Dictionaries does. I've added that information to my answer.